# Transform Sales Order to Invoice Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm having trouble converting a sales order to an invoice order using suitescript. This is my code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'],
function(record) {
    function afterSubmit(context) {
        var orderId = context.newRecord.id;
        var invoiceRecord = record.transform({
            fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
            fromId: orderId,
            toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
            isDynamic: true
        });
    }

    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Account: TSTDRV1714128
Environment: Production
Date & Time: 6/28/2018 12:56 pm
Record Type: Item Shipment
Internal ID: 16547
Execution Time: 0.00s
Script Usage: 0
Script: invoiceCreator
Type: User Event
Function: afterSubmit
Error: JS_EXCEPTION
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_INITIALIZE_REF","message":"You can not initialize invoice: invalid reference 16547.","stack":["createError(N/error)","afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/UserEventScript.js:13)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"INVALID_INITIALIZE_REF","details":"You can not initialize invoice: invalid reference 16547.","userEvent":"aftersubmit","stackTrace":["createError(N/error)","afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/UserEventScript.js:13)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false}
```

I've seen some sample solutions for this problem but I still keep getting the same error. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing might be the due to a number of causes.
The two most common are:

- Your order has the wrong status to invoice. You may need to fulfill it first or set your account to enable "Invoice in Advance of Fulfillment"
- Your order may be meant for a Cash Sale. If it has a payment method it will generally be for a cash sale rather than invoice.

I often wrap a try catch block around transformations and 'make a guess' when transforming to customer bill. Based on terms and payment method I'll try invoice or cash sale as the customer bill transaction type and if that doesn't work I'll try the other customer bill transaction type.

Comment: Glad to help. Could you reply in comments with what the error was to help others?

Comment: Well I don't get an error anymore, but the code doesn't work. No invoice is created. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: If that’s all your code you also need to save the initialized invoice

Comment: It would be great if you could leave error messages and solutions in your original post so people reading this get the same benefit you intended to get by posting here.